# How do I improve my code to get integer values from regex named capture groups?

Tags: regex, rust

My Rust code parses a log file and accumulates some information:

```
use regex::Regex;

fn parse(line: &str) {
    let re_str = concat!(
        r"^\s+(?P<qrw1>\d+)\|(?P<qrw2>\d+)",//qrw 0|0
        r"\s+(?P<arw1>\d+)\|(?P<arw2>\d+)",//arw 34|118
        );
    let re = Regex::new(re_str).unwrap();
    match re.captures(line) {
        Some(caps) => {
            let qrw1 = caps.name("qrw1").unwrap().as_str().parse::<i32>().unwrap();
            let qrw2 = caps.name("qrw2").unwrap().as_str().parse::<i32>().unwrap();
            let arw1 = caps.name("arw1").unwrap().as_str().parse::<i32>().unwrap();
            let arw2 = caps.name("arw2").unwrap().as_str().parse::<i32>().unwrap();
        }

        None => todo!(),
    }
}
```

<sup>[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=74ed99a1c608785e537df50f85795f90)</sup>

This works as expected, but I think those long chained calls which I created to get integer values of regex capture groups are a bit ugly. How do I make them shorter/nicer?

Comment: Questions asking for general improvements ("How do I improve my code") are better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: “those long chained calls […] are a bit ugly”, well, a general advice for any language: If you repeat yourself, make a function. Also, you should handle errors rather than ignoring them with `unwrap`, and the `?` operator would be shorter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing you could do is extract the parsing into a closure `internal_parse`:

```
fn parse(line: &str) -> Option<(i32, i32, i32, i32)> {
    let re_str = concat!(
        r"^\s+(?P<qrw1>\d+)\|(?P<qrw2>\d+)",//qrw 0|0
        r"\s+(?P<arw1>\d+)\|(?P<arw2>\d+)",//arw 34|118
    );
    let re = Regex::new(re_str).unwrap();
    match re.captures(line) {
        Some(caps) => {
            let internal_parse = |key| {
                caps.name(key).unwrap().as_str().parse::<i32>().unwrap()
            };
            let qrw1 = internal_parse("qrw1");
            let qrw2 = internal_parse("qrw2");
            let arw1 = internal_parse("arw1");
            let arw2 = internal_parse("arw2");
            Some((qrw1, qrw2, arw1, arw2))
        }
        None => None,
    }
}
```

However, you should keep in mind that `parse::<i32>` may fail. (Consider e.g. the string `"  00|45   57|4894444444444444444444444   "`.)

You could also try to solve this problem by using a parser combinator library (the crates `nom`, `pest` or `combine` come to one's mind) that traverses the string and spits out the `i32`s directly (so that you do not have to `parse` manually after matching via `regex`).